# How do I fix my armature's rotations

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm making a humanoid rig in blender and whenever I rotate the forearm, it will deform it horribly and ruin the upper arm as well. This also happens with the legs.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brlv.jpg)

Comment: maybe you need to change the IK pole angle?

Comment: Your weights are wrong. Try to reassign them. In your case the simpliest solution if you assign the Vertex Groups in Edit Mode.